# Showing the general solution to the given vector in terms of other known vectors

Tags: vectors

If a and b are vectors perpendicular to each other
Then is it okay to say that the general solution to $\vec{r} \times \vec{a} = \vec{b}$  is
$$\vec{r}= \frac{\vec{r}\cdot \vec{a}}{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}}\vec{a}+\frac{1}{\vec{a} \cdot  \vec{a}}(\vec{a} \times \vec{b})\,?$$

I did cross product with a vector to the given vector equation to get the above result will we really say the solution is that only as such $x$ has dependance on $r$ again isn't ?

Comment: The expression you found satisfies the original equation when $x$ is any real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with $\vec{r} \times \vec{a} = \vec{b} $

where $\vec{a}, \vec{b} $ are given, we have from the properties of cross product that $\vec{r}$ must be perpendicular to $\vec{b}$.  Clearly we also must have $\vec{b} $ perpendicular to $\vec{a}$.  Therefore, our solution $\vec{r}$ lies in the plane spanned by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} $, i.e.

$ \vec{r} = t \vec{a} + s \left(\vec{a} \times \vec{b} \right) $

Plug this expression into the original equation

$ \left( t \vec{a} + s \left(\vec{a} \times \vec{b} \right)\right) \times \vec{a} = \vec{b}$

Using the fact that $\vec{a} \times \vec{a} = 0 $ and

$\left( \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \right) \times \vec{a} = - \vec{a} (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} ) + \vec{b} (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} ) $

and using the fact that $ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0 $ because they are pendicular, then

$s = \dfrac{1}{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} } $

Therefore, the general solution is

$\vec{r} = t \vec{a} + \dfrac{ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} } { \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}} $

where $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks thats what i was needed , but can from my way we can let that x to be a free variable or its not the right method ?

Comment: Because a.r/a.a is dependent on r again?

Comment: Exactly.  $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{r}$ depends on $\vec{r}$, so the expression will be ambiguous.